# jQuery trigger click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a search button on it.

in my Javascript i have a click event that looks like this:

```
if(blah){
  $('#search').click();
}

$('#search').on('click', function(){
  // Do something
});
```

What would be the reason the if statement wouldn't click the button to cause the `onclick` to fire?

All of this is wrapped in an `onReady` as well.

The html on the page is a standard button:

```
<button id='search' type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Search RefID</button>
```

Comment: if `blah` evals to a false... triggering a click will also only run the defined click handler, not the native functionality

Comment: It doesn't, I put an alert before and after the `.click()` so I know it gets there

Comment: You seem to bind the handler **after** you triggered the click. The handler is not executed because it does not exist (at that moment).

Comment: @FelixKling that was it :( my mistake

Comment: @FelixKling I think you should turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to bind the handler **after** you triggered the click. The handler is not executed because it does not exist (at that moment).

Put the if-clause after the click-handler and it works:

**http://jsfiddle.net/kksgj4xL/**

```
var blah = true;

$('#search').click(function(){
  alert("poep");
});

if(blah){
  $('#search').click();
}
```